# Unity 3D 5.4 2D Collisions Not Working?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, collision

I am working on a very small Unity 5.4 project, I have several "pellets" which in the game world have a Rigid Body 2D and 2D polygon collider attached. I then also have a ball which has a Rigid Body 2D, Polygon Colider and also a Physics Material which allows the ball to bounce  into other objects.

The following code is attached to a script on the ball would do something... anything when it hits the green pellets but nothing happens. I don't actually want it to quit the application this was just for example purposes.

The following are the properties of both objects:

[image]

```
public class BallBounce : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        //activate camera because I am lazy
        var cam = GameObject.Find ("camera");
        var ball = GameObject.Find ("ball");
        Rigidbody2D rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        cam.SetActive (true);
                    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
            }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag  ==  "Bricks") {
            Application.Quit ();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The Application.Quit() doesnt  work in the editor. You have to build your game and launch it as a standalone to make the application quit.

Comment: Hey thanks. I changed it up to try and destroy the bricks it comes in contact with but also does nothing:

Updated code:

Comment: void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
 {
  if (col.gameObject.tag == "Bricks") {
   Destroy (col.gameObject);
  }

Answer (score 0):

`Application.Quit();` does not work in the Editor. It is used for Standalone Build. Replace that with  `UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;`

Now, if you want it to work in both Editor and Standalone Build:

```
void Start () 
{
    //activate camera because I am lazy
    var cam = GameObject.Find ("camera");
    var ball = GameObject.Find ("ball");
    Rigidbody2D rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    cam.SetActive (true);
    Debug.Log("Start Called!");
}

void Update () 
{

}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    Debug.Log("Collision detected: "+col.gameObject.name);
    if (col.gameObject.tag  ==  "Bricks") {
       #if UNITY_EDITOR
       UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;
       #else
       Application.Quit();
       #endif
     }
}
```

Next time when testing if something is true or false, simply use `Debug.Log("It works");`

Comment: it feels like there is something fundamentally wrong here.  Even writting to the console fails:

Comment: void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
 {
  if (col.gameObject.tag == "Bricks") {
   Debug.Log ("Collision Detected");
  }
 
 }

Comment: @RaeMichelleRichards Why not put Debug.Log("It works"); in your Start function and check if you see anything

Comment: Moving the collision detection causes a compiler error

Comment: @RaeMichelleRichards I updated my answer again with bunch of Debugs.Log. Please copy the code and replace it with your code. Tell me what you see in the Consolse log